# Getting this error with split function in R

Tags: r, split, subset

I'm new to R and learning it via Coursera and during one of the assignments  outline in [this pdf](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_c79abb16c67d30f2dc8785e5abcf70d4_ProgAssignment3.pdf?Expires=1485820800&Signature=CcI2z-0cnibrLt7AwcQo9CKETkIP45Qf5sTDnuR1vC-~ZXAs6OEZSNx34NlYPUXwCG3rOQmCjpA0CgPf~Ql8uv4qUZhqeIpoTZGRjiQ0nOoSAU5OVTucKprCmI0Xye8vYfyD~npvpTzRbZRMP4C~gCZ4cQU17hht3n1W5WbHfMc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A) I encountered the following error:

```
Error in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :   

group length is 0 but data length > 0
```

Basically I'm stuck in part 2 Finding best Hospital in the state part, and while writing function for it I test its constructs via console. So far to test it I wrote this piece of code:

```
outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
outcome[, 11] <- as.numeric(outcome[, 11]) # 30-day mortality for the heart attack
outcome[, 17] <- as.numeric(outcome[, 17]) # 30-day mortality for the heart failure 
outcome[, 23] <- as.numeric(outcome[, 23]) # 30-day mortality for the pneumonia 
outcome <- outcome[, c(2, 7, 11)] # Subsetting three columns
outcome <- na.omit(outcome) # omitting na
names(outcome) <- c("hospital", "state", "outcome") #Renaming the columns
outcome <- split(outcome, outcome$State) # Splitting it based on states
```

I'm also attaching the [Hospital Sample](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2FProgAssignment3-data.zip)

Hope anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `state`, not `State`. Look at the data:

```
> head(outcome)
                          hospital state outcome
1 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL    14.3
2    MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL    18.5
3   ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL    18.1
```

you named it `state`, and then tried to split on a column called `State`. R is case sensitive.